# getting a usable TCP port from Windows Azure Service Bus

Tags: java, azure, tcp, httplistener, servicebus

I am trying to get a service bus connection to connect from an Azure Application to a Server in house. There will be multiple Servers, running a mix of Java and .NET. The in house server is currently set to talk HTTP. the Azure Client will do a HTTP Post to the Server, and get a response.

The question I have is: How do i get a usable port from the Azure Service Bus? Any code i have seen shows me how to open a WCF service and listen on that, but i want to open a HTTPListener... Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pretty much what's its rigged to do right now. routing http posts isn't a common usage. In your situation, I might try to create a port bridge. It requires an agent on both ends, but once created, you can essentially forward any TCP/IP based traffice. The examples that are out there are a bit dated, but they should still work. They also allow for the multi-plexing of connections to help manage the connection costs.

Alternatively, have you looked into Azure Connect? If allows a server-to-server trusted connection that may also accomplish what you need.

You can find out more about the port bridge at: http://vasters.com/clemensv/PermaLink,guid,3e35d8bd-b755-453f-8c63-1a57c570eb4c.aspx

Comment: thanks for the info. looking into it now. Azure connect sounds interesting, but does it work on Non Windows Environments?

Comment: Right now AzureConnect requires a windows-only client to be installed on your end.  I'm not aware of your security needs, but have you considered making your Azure instance public?  You can secure with cert-based auth (or any other system) and achieve a decent level of security.

Comment: its not the service on Azure that is the problem... The Internal servers, which will be run in a few different places, cannot be accessed by the internet. the idea with Service Bus is that a Windows Service (or Java service...) will start, talk to the Azure Service and get an End Point. this way, when ever the Azure needs to talk to a service, it can call based on the end URL and do the magic.

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like the port bridge may be your best bet. With the exception of message buffers, most of the Azure AppFabric service bus approaches are not overly interoperable. But I believe we'll see that change based on Clemens Vaster's PDC10 session "Future of Azure AppFabric".